# Reading encoded string from DataGridView in c#

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, character-encoding

I am having problems with reading Korean characters from datagridview. I read korean alphabets from csv and written them to datagridview. My method is as follows:

```
int encoder = 949;
public void DisplayPCM()
{
    StreamReader sr;
    Encoding korean = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoder);
    string selectedDirectory = projectPath + "\\Spec";
    string filePath = selectedDirectory + "\\" + functionfile;

    pcmpath = new StringBuilder(filePath);
    if (Directory.Exists(selectedDirectory))
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            try
            {
                sr = new StreamReader(filePath, korean);
                int lineCount = 0;
                StringBuilder readLine = new StringBuilder(sr.ReadLine());
                while (readLine.ToString() != null && readLine.ToString() != "")
                {
                    string[] substr = readLine.ToString().Split(',');
                    if (lineCount >= 1)
                    {
                        dPCM.Rows[lineCount - 1].Cells[0].Value = substr[0];
                        dPCM.Rows[lineCount - 1].Cells[1].Value = substr[1];
                        dPCM.Rows[lineCount - 1].Cells[2].Value = substr[2];
                        dPCM.Rows[lineCount - 1].Cells[3].Value = substr[3];
                    }

                    readLine = new StringBuilder(sr.ReadLine());
                    lineCount++;
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in Part File \n" + filePath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(filePath + "\n does not exist.");
        }

    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Until this point, there are no problems. The characters in datagridview are displayed in korean alphabets.
Now i have to edit the text in datagridview and read back the text and save it in csv file and reload this csv file text to datagridview.
When I did this procedure, I get some chinese text. It looks like when reading the string from datagridview, there is a problem. For reading datagridview text and saving it in csv file, my steps are as follows:

```
private void Save_PCM()
{
    DirectoryInfo di;
    StreamWriter sw = null;
    int rowcount = 0;

    StringBuilder Newnum, NewName, Newlower, Newupper;
    try
    {                
        Encoding korean = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoder);
        string selectedDirectory = projectPath + "\\Spec";
        string filePath = selectedDirectory + "\\" + functionfile;
        pcmpath = new StringBuilder(filePath);

        sw = new StreamWriter(pcmpath.ToString());
        sw.WriteLine("NO,NAME,Lower SPEC,Upper SPEC");

        while (dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            Newnum = new StringBuilder(dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            NewName = new StringBuilder(dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            Newlower = new StringBuilder(dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            Newupper = new StringBuilder(dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            if (Newnum == null || NewName == null || Newlower == null || Newupper == null)
                break;
            sw.WriteLine(Newnum + "," + NewName + "," + Newlower + "," + Newupper);
            rowcount++;
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Project name error" + Environment.NewLine + e.Message);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter all values in PCM" + Environment.NewLine + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sw != null)
            sw.Close();
    }
}
```

I think that I have to read datagridview cell values by including some encoding methods but I am clueless.
How can I read the text encoded in korean language from datagridview. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you write them back in the CSV?

Comment: Also, note that the code you've shown here wouldn't compile - please show *real* code, ideally as a [mcve].

Comment: How exactly `temp` looks like and which method you use to determine *it's wrong* (e.g. by looking in VS? looking into csv-file? using which viewer?)?

Comment: I have pasted my code as is. Sorry for creating confusion before.

Comment: What about `sw = new StreamWriter(pcmpath.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(encoder));` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it looks like it works. I thought that the problem was in reading the encoded text from datagridview but the problem was in writing the encoded text to csv file. I made changes in function to read the data into .csv file. I declared a filestream path and added the filestream path and encoding to the streamwriter.

```
private void Save_PCM()
{
    DirectoryInfo di;
    FileStream stream = null;
    StreamWriter sw = null;
    int rowcount = 0;

    StringBuilder Newnum, NewName, Newlower, Newupper;
    try
    {                
        Encoding korean = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoder);
        string selectedDirectory = projectPath + "\\Spec";
        string filePath = selectedDirectory + "\\" + functionfile;
        pcmpath = new StringBuilder(filePath);

        stream = new FileStream(pcmpath.ToString(), FileMode.Create);    // overwrite existing file
        sw = new StreamWriter(stream, korean);
        sw.WriteLine("NO,NAME,Lower SPEC,Upper SPEC");

        while (dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            Newnum = new StringBuilder(dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            byte[] bb = korean.GetBytes(dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            NewName = new StringBuilder(Encoding.Default.GetString(bb));                    
            Newlower = new StringBuilder(dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            Newupper = new StringBuilder(dPCM.Rows[rowcount].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            if (Newnum == null || NewName == null || Newlower == null || Newupper == null)
                break;                    
            sw.WriteLine(Newnum + "," + NewName + "," + Newlower + "," + Newupper);
            rowcount++;
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Project name error" + Environment.NewLine + e.Message);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter all values in PCM" + Environment.NewLine + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sw != null)
            sw.Close();
    }
}
```